# Symbol's value as variable is void: ‘rvm

Tags: emacs, rvm

I'm trying to install rvm.el from https://github.com/senny/rvm.el and after copying said file and copying the elisp into my .emacs files, emacs is giving me an error of "Symbol's value as variable is void: ‘rvm" and I'm not sure what's wrong. Could someone point me in the right direction please?

my .emacs

```
;; Update load path.                                                                                                                                                    
(add-to-list 'load-path "~/.emacs.d")

;; Interactively Do Things (highly recommended, but not strictly required)                                                                                              
(require 'ido)
(ido-mode t)

;; Rinari                                                                                                                                                               
(add-to-list 'load-path "~/.emacs.d/rinari")
(require 'rinari)

;; RVM                                                                                                                                                                  
(require ‘rvm)
(rvm-use-default) ;; use rvm’s default ruby for the current Emacs session
```

output of emacs --debug-init:

```
Debugger entered--Lisp error: (void-variable ‘rvm)
  (require ‘rvm)
  eval-buffer(#<buffer  *load*> nil "/home/levi/.emacs" nil t)  ; Reading at buffer position 265
  load-with-code-conversion("/home/levi/.emacs" "/home/levi/.emacs" t t)
  load("~/.emacs" t t)
  #[nil "^H\205\264^@   \306=\203^Q^@\307^H\310Q\2027^@ \311=\2033^@\312\307\313\314#\203#^@\315\2027^@\312\307\313\316#\203/^@\317\2027^@\315\2027^@\307^H\320Q^Z\321^$
  command-line()
  normal-top-level()
```

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Eyeballing that code, you have some non-ascii character in place of the apostrophe for quoting `rvm`

`(require ‘rvm)` should be `(require 'rvm)`

That's why Emacs sees it as a variable to be evaluated, rather than a quoted symbol.